# Nowing the number of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I know in which position "Januar" in the array is (in a number)?^
In the end, I want to get 0 for "January" and 1 for "February" .

```
var Monat = ["January", "February"]
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

So in your case

```
 Monat.indexOf("January")
```

Should return 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of Array.prototype to find the index.

```js
var Monat = ["January", "February"];
function findIndex(day) {
  return Monat.findIndex((x) => x === day);
}

const index = findIndex("January");
console.log(index);
const index2 = findIndex("February");
console.log(index2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf for this. it will return the index of the first matched item in the array if found or -1 otherwise.

```js
var Monat = ["January", "February"];

console.log(Monat.indexOf("January")); //0

console.log(Monat.indexOf("February")); //1

console.log(Monat.indexOf("not exists")); //-1
```